# Aligning Cartosat-2 Image?

Tags: qgis-3, remote-sensing, georeferencing, cartosat-2

Recently our company purchased Cartosat-2 Image from NRSC. Our Mining Lease area Boundary is not aligning with Image.It is around 100 meter offset.We are using QGIS 3.4.Spatial reference  of Cartosat-2 UTM Zone-45 and WGS-84 datum.Project spatial reference is GCS WGS-84.On the fly projection is there.
It aligned properly with LISS-4 Image.

Answer (score 1):

Cartosat-2 scenes can have a misalignment of up to 100m. So your observation of the image not aligning with your shapefile is common. To solve your problem you need to **georeference** the Cartosat-2 image onto your shapefile or onto your LISS-4 image, which will be much easier and 'failure proof' depending on the size of your area. The process basically involves searching for common points in both images and calculating a transformation function. There are tools in QGIS for that.

Comment: @Ray Please consider upvoting and accepting this answer if it answered your question.